# "this.context" returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out why:

- I have react _ react-dom 16.8x
- I have a component between my Provider and my Consumer to avoid cyclic call between the two aforementioned elements.

I would my context be accessible directly in lifecycle component and seen ReactJS propose the `this.context`'s method to do that.

Here my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wyxympvyw7)

Here my reactjs snippet

```
import React, {Component}from "react"; 
import "./App.css";


// first we will make a new context
const MyContext = React.createContext();

// Then create a provider Component
class MyProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Wes',
    age: 100,
    cool: true
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state,
        growAYearOlder: () => this.setState({
          age: this.state.age + 1
        })
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

const Family = (props) => (
  <div className="family">
    <Person />
  </div>
)

class Person extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){ 
    console.log("context: ", this.context)
  }
  render() {
    console.log("context: ", this.context)
    return (
      <div className="person">
        <MyContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <p>Age: {context.state.age}</p>
              <p>Name: {context.state.name}</p>
              <button onClick={context.growAYearOlder}></button>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </MyContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyProvider>
        <div>
          <p>I am the app</p>
          <Family />
        </div>
      </MyProvider>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Why `this.context` is empty?

Any hint would be great, 
thanks

Comment: Hi since I have a very similar code I have tested your sandbox on React 17.0.2 and found that when introducing a `componentDidMount` and `setState` to the `MyProvider`, it doesn't return the changed values in `Person`'s `componentDidMount`. Do you have any idea why that happens? [Forked link] (https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-smoke-qhihc?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set contextType to consume a context.

On the [react website](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype) it specifies as much anyway.

So the only change required:

```
class Person extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){ 
    console.log("context: ", this.context)
  }
  render() {
    console.log("context: ", this.context)
    return (
      <div className="person">
        <MyContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <p>Age: {context.state.age}</p>
              <p>Name: {context.state.name}</p>
              <button onClick={context.growAYearOlder}></button>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </MyContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
Person.contextType = MyContext;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to `MyContext` in `Person`, you can wrap `Person` in the consumer and pass in `context` when you render it in `Family`:

```
const Family = (props) => (
  <div className="family">
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => {
        <Person context={context} />
      }}
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  </div>
)


class Person extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){ 
    console.log("context: ", this.props.context)
  }
  render() {
    const { context } = this.props;
    console.log("context: ", context)
    return (
      <div className="person">
        <React.Fragment>
          <p>Age: {context.state.age}</p>
          <p>Name: {context.state.name}</p>
          <button onClick={context.growAYearOlder}></button>
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```